# jQuery и работа с sessionStorage. Как получить реальные данные?

Tags: javascript, jquery, img

Сразу отмечу, что свои познания, как в native JS, так и в jQuery расцениваю, как ОЧЕНЬ базовые, потому, если буду нести чушь, поправьте меня, пожалуйста.

Есть страница, на которой в `sessionStorage` заносится ссылка на изображение:

```html
<script>
  sessionStorage['requiredImage'] = 'https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/AAEAAQAAAAAAAALwAAAAJDliZTVkOTcyLWQ0NzUtNDNlZC1hZmEwLTY1NTQ0ZDBjNTE5ZA.jpg';
  // изображение взято от фонаря
</script>
<a href="другая_страница.html">Тыц</a>
```

После чего происходит переход на другую_страницу, где происходит следующее:

```js
var image;

$(function() {
  var temp = document.createElement("img");
  temp.setAttribute("id", "image");

  // Если нужный нам элемент не существует в sessionStorage, то берём нечто по умолчанию
  if (sessionStorage['requiredImage'] === undefined) {
    temp.setAttribute("src", "http://zefirka.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/samaya-krasivaya-priroda-dlya-puteshestvij-sovsem-ryadom-1.jpg");
  } else {
    temp.setAttribute("src", sessionStorage['requiredImage']);
    sessionStorage.clear(); // очищаем
  }

  document.getElementById("work-area").appendChild(temp);
  // Берём этот элемент при помощи jQuery
  image = $('#image');
  console.log(image);
  // Что характерно, тут мы будем иметь все характеристики как надо, но
  console.log(image[0]['width']); // 0
  console.log(image[0]['height']); // 0
  console.log(image[0]['naturalWidth']); // 0
  console.log(image[0]['naturalHeight']); // 0
});
```

```css
#work-area {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="work-area"></div>

<article id="main"></article>
```

Если добавить на страницу кнопку и обрабатывать изображение по клику на ней - то всё отрабатывает нормально. Я так понимаю, что это оптимизатор балуется, правильно? В любом случае, верные данные по `width` и `height` мне нужно получить сразу, а не по нажатию кнопок или какому-либо иному событию зависящему от конечного пользователя. Вот как их можно получить?

Ко всему прочему, если изображение вставить сразу видимым, то размеры можно получить по `image.width()` и `image.height()`, но мне нужно, чтобы оно было именно невидимым до того, как мой скрипт его обработает должным образом. Естественно, что при таком подходе эти функции будут возвращать нули.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нули там потому что `#work-area` скрыт, к его элементам нет доступа. Скрывайте этот блок, например, таким образом:

```
#work-area {
  height:0;
  width:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Так у вас изображение не будет отображаться, но данные о нем будут вам доступны.

UPD. Повесил обработчик `.load()` на изображение, потому что надо брать его размеры только после того, как оно загрузится. `sessionStorage` закомментировал, потому что тут нет возможности показать с ним пример.

```js
var image;

$(function() {
  var temp = document.createElement("img");
  temp.setAttribute("id", "image");

  // Если нужный нам элемент не существует в sessionStorage, то берём нечто по умолчанию
  //if (sessionStorage['requiredImage'] === undefined) {
    temp.setAttribute("src", "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&bg=660000&txt=400%C3%97400&w=400&h=400");
  /*} else {
    temp.setAttribute("src", sessionStorage['requiredImage']);
    sessionStorage.clear(); // очищаем
  }*/

  document.getElementById("work-area").appendChild(temp);
  // Берём этот элемент при помощи jQuery
  image = $('#image').load(function(){
  // Что характерно, тут мы будем иметь все характеристики как надо, но
  console.log(image[0]['width']); // 0
  console.log(image[0]['height']); // 0
  console.log(image[0]['naturalWidth']); // 0
  console.log(image[0]['naturalHeight']); // 0
  });
  //console.log(image);
});
```

```css
#work-area {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="work-area"></div>

<article id="main"></article>
```

Comment: То же самое выходит. То есть, только по действию от пользователя данные получаются корректно. До этого они всё равно нулевые. Как от всех 4х параметров объекта, так и от функций width и height.

Comment: См. обновленный ответ.

Comment: Да, увидел. Благодарю, так действительно работает вместе с 2.1.1